Is there a way to set "Session ID" when using Azure.Monitor.OpenTelemetry.AspNetCore
We are using Application Insights for our distributed logging. After having migrated from Application Insights SDK (Classic API) to the recommended OpenTelemetry Distro we are seeing a reduced usability in the UI part of Application Insights. Specifically in regards to not being able to track a session.
Previously we was able to use an implementation of ITelemetryProcessor to setup UserContext and SessionContext. Now we are adding Tags in a implementation of BaseProcessor. But I cannot seem to get the "Session Id" set so Application Insights can see and use it. Everything is logged as a Custom Property.
The same issue was happening for User Id. But this could be solved by setting a tag with the key: "endUser.id". Is there anything similar for Session Id?

Along with the OpenTelemetry, I have added the Javascript SDK in the .cshtml and able to get the Session and UserID for requests and Dependency logs.Image

I am able to see the Session and User ID in the Applications Insights.

Along with the OpenTelemetry I have used the Javascript SDK.

I have referred this MSDoc to configure Open Telemetry  and my SOThread to configure Javascript SDK in .NET Applications.

Add the above mentioned Javascript SDK in .cshtml file(I have added it in _Layout.cshtml file).


My Program.cs file:
using Azure.Monitor.OpenTelemetry.AspNetCore;
builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetry().UseAzureMonitor();

OR
builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetry().UseAzureMonitor(options => {
    options.ConnectionString = "InstrumentationKey=********;IngestionEndpoint=https://****-0.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://australiacentral.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/;ApplicationId=********";
});

My _Layout.cshtml:
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - WebApplication2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/WebApplication2.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        !function(T, l, y) { var S = T.location, k = "script", D = "instrumentationKey", C = "ingestionendpoint", I = "disableExceptionTracking", E = "ai.device.", b = "toLowerCase", w = "crossOrigin", N = "POST", e = "appInsightsSDK", t = y.name || "appInsights"; (y.name || T[e]) && (T[e] = t); var n = T[t] || function(d) { var g = !1, f = !1, m = { initialize: !0, queue: [], sv: "5", version: 2, config: d }; function v(e, t) { var n = {}, a = "Browser"; return n[E + "id"] = a[b](), n[E + "type"] = a, n["ai.operation.name"] = S && S.pathname || "_unknown_", n["ai.internal.sdkVersion"] = "javascript:snippet_" + (m.sv || m.version), { time: function() { var e = new Date; function t(e) { var t = "" + e; return 1 === t.length && (t = "0" + t), t } return e.getUTCFullYear() + "-" + t(1 + e.getUTCMonth()) + "-" + t(e.getUTCDate()) + "T" + t(e.getUTCHours()) + ":" + t(e.getUTCMinutes()) + ":" + t(e.getUTCSeconds()) + "." + ((e.getUTCMilliseconds() / 1e3).toFixed(3) + "").slice(2, 5) + "Z" }(), iKey: e, name: "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights." + e.replace(/-/g, "") + "." + t, sampleRate: 100, tags: n, data: { baseData: { ver: 2 } } } } var h = d.url || y.src; if (h) { function a(e) { var t, n, a, i, r, o, s, c, u, p, l; g = !0, m.queue = [], f || (f = !0, t = h, s = function() { var e = {}, t = d.connectionString; if (t) for (var n = t.split(";"), a = 0; a < n.length; a++) { var i = n[a].split("="); 2 === i.length && (e[i[0][b]()] = i[1]) } if (!e[C]) { var r = e.endpointsuffix, o = r ? e.location : null; e[C] = "https://" + (o ? o + "." : "") + "dc." + (r || "services.visualstudio.com") } return e }(), c = s[D] || d[D] || "", u = s[C], p = u ? u + "/v2/track" : d.endpointUrl, (l = []).push((n = "SDK LOAD Failure: Failed to load Application Insights SDK script (See stack for details)", a = t, i = p, (o = (r = v(c, "Exception")).data).baseType = "ExceptionData", o.baseData.exceptions = [{ typeName: "SDKLoadFailed", message: n.replace(/\./g, "-"), hasFullStack: !1, stack: n + "\nSnippet failed to load [" + a + "] -- Telemetry is disabled\nHelp Link: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2128109\nHost: " + (S && S.pathname || "_unknown_") + "\nEndpoint: " + i, parsedStack: [] }], r)), l.push(function(e, t, n, a) { var i = v(c, "Message"), r = i.data; r.baseType = "MessageData"; var o = r.baseData; return o.message = 'AI (Internal): 99 message:"' + ("SDK LOAD Failure: Failed to load Application Insights SDK script (See stack for details) (" + n + ")").replace(/\"/g, "") + '"', o.properties = { endpoint: a }, i }(0, 0, t, p)), function(e, t) { if (JSON) { var n = T.fetch; if (n && !y.useXhr) n(t, { method: N, body: JSON.stringify(e), mode: "cors" }); else if (XMLHttpRequest) { var a = new XMLHttpRequest; a.open(N, t), a.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json"), a.send(JSON.stringify(e)) } } }(l, p)) } function i(e, t) { f || setTimeout(function() { !t && m.core || a() }, 500) } var e = function() { var n = l.createElement(k); n.src = h; var e = y[w]; return !e && "" !== e || "undefined" == n[w] || (n[w] = e), n.onload = i, n.onerror = a, n.onreadystatechange = function(e, t) { "loaded" !== n.readyState && "complete" !== n.readyState || i(0, t) }, n }(); y.ld < 0 ? l.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(e) : setTimeout(function() { l.getElementsByTagName(k)[0].parentNode.appendChild(e) }, y.ld || 0) } try { m.cookie = l.cookie } catch (p) { } function t(e) { for (; e.length;)!function(t) { m[t] = function() { var e = arguments; g || m.queue.push(function() { m[t].apply(m, e) }) } }(e.pop()) } var n = "track", r = "TrackPage", o = "TrackEvent"; t([n + "Event", n + "PageView", n + "Exception", n + "Trace", n + "DependencyData", n + "Metric", n + "PageViewPerformance", "start" + r, "stop" + r, "start" + o, "stop" + o, "addTelemetryInitializer", "setAuthenticatedUserContext", "clearAuthenticatedUserContext", "flush"]), m.SeverityLevel = { Verbose: 0, Information: 1, Warning: 2, Error: 3, Critical: 4 }; var s = (d.extensionConfig || {}).ApplicationInsightsAnalytics || {}; if (!0 !== d[I] && !0 !== s[I]) { var c = "onerror"; t(["_" + c]); var u = T[c]; T[c] = function(e, t, n, a, i) { var r = u && u(e, t, n, a, i); return !0 !== r && m["_" + c]({ message: e, url: t, lineNumber: n, columnNumber: a, error: i }), r }, d.autoExceptionInstrumented = !0 } return m }(y.cfg); function a() { y.onInit && y.onInit(n) } (T[t] = n).queue && 0 === n.queue.length ? (n.queue.push(a), n.trackPageView({})) : a() }(window, document, {

            src: "https://js.monitor.azure.com/scripts/b/ai.2.min.js",
            crossOrigin: "anonymous",
            cfg: {
                instrumentationKey: "cb575297-5399-4a39-9313-2bfe76e5109f"
            }
        });

    </script>
</head>


I can see the Session ID and  User ID  in PageView Dependency log properties.

Transaction Search -  End-to-end transaction details

